# Setting size of sprite to another object in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a sprite the same size as a mesh on the screen. Here is an image of what I have. I want the big blue sprite to be the same size as the small, gray mesh with the particles coming out.'

[image]

Here is the code I am using to try and accomplish this.

```
void Update () {
    renderer.enabled = true;
    renderer.transform.position = GetComponentInParent<BoxCollider>().transform.position;
    renderer.transform.localScale = GetComponentInParent<BoxCollider>().transform.localScale;


}
```

The renderer is set to the SpriteRenderer of the blue arrow sprite. Any help with figuring this out is extremely appreciated.

Comment: it's very unlikely you would do this in Update().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're asking is to have the sprites "snap" to each other so that they're lined up perfectly pixel-wise, there's an easier method than scripting it.  When you import the sprite, take a look at its import settings.  Adjust the "Pixel to Unit" value to the dimension of your sprite--you can scale it just as you like then.

If that isn't what you're after, please clarify what you're trying to do.